# Are indexes need for parts of primary key?

Tags: postgresql, index, primary-key

In Postgres, is it beneficial to query performance to create an index on field2 in the following table if I intend to sometimes use queries with only field2 in the WHERE clause?

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    field1   INT NOT NULL,
    field2   INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_my_table PRIMARY KEY (field1, field2)
);
```

example query ("get all the records where field2 = my_value"):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field2 = my_value;
```

In other words should I also include:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_my_table_field2 ON my_table(field2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compound index can also support queries that compare columns that are at the beginning of the indexed values (but aren't all). So an index on `(field1, field2)` (which is implicitly created for a primary key) would also support queries that compare only `field1`.

But it cannot support queries that only compare columns of its end (but aren't all). So `(field1, field2)` won't support queries that only compare `field2`.

So yes, you need to create an extra index only on `(field2)` to have a chance it supports queries only comparing `field2`.